# datatables or php pagination for large database queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

Currently I am using codeigniter for a website, in a page I query the database and then create a table to display the results with jquery datatables but with 10,000 records the page is starting to get slow around 5 seconds to load.
So my question is would I be better off using codeigniter pagination library to get a smaller chunk of record per request ?

Any suggestions on how to handle this problem?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're asking for opinions, which are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Marc B. Have a great day!

Comment: which version of datatables for codeigniter you are using? i'm starting to work with this version https://github.com/zepernick/Codeigniter-DataTables its for Codeigniter 3 and it is very fast.

Comment: Thank you cartalot, I am using the plugging from datatables cdn, I am going to checkout the library you suggested, thank you.

Comment: DataTables docs advice to use AJAX call for large sets of DB data. It can be achieved with setting `DataTable.serverSide: true` as pointed on [this page](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) and url of PHP script (in your case controller/method/argument).

Comment: cool - hey if you end up trying it and have questions or discover things - please post on the codeigniter.com forum - would be great to collaborate with someone on implementing it, and the thread could help new people.

Comment: will do cartalot, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, first, thank you all for your responses it got me in the direction for the solution and other possible ones for the future.

This is how I solve the problem:

datatables Server-side processing.
 My table was loading  on an average of 5 seconds, got it to load in 0.0798 seconds.

Here is a link to the documentation on using [server side processing](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)
 just use the example code (read the comments) in a function in your controller, create a new library with the file ssp.class.php, name it Ssp.php and then just load it on your controller with `$this->load->library('Ssp');`

So far working great, I will post a full tutorial on codeigniter forum.

Comment: cool that would be great. just a note i went back to the app i'm working on with the library i linked to - over 17,000 records - default page opens instantly. searching and retrieving records happens in close to real time. and page results are not just text - 5 searchable columns, and 2 columns with forms, submit buttons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

yes it will be better to use codeigniter pagination library to get a smaller chunk of record per request.

using a lazy loading technique itch pagination mixed with data filtering will be better and more sophisticated approach.

Comment: I saw on another website that there might be problem with pagination because one would have to do  a request per each record set, I am confused on sacrificing load time vs. database hits.

Comment: actually there is a great mechanic behind lazy loading approach, you can specify a custom loading technique.
itch time the user press the paginationTemplate you can get the data from the main memory.
for example you can save data on in-memory list to mimic the real dataSource.